# Is it possible to install gcc 5+ version on redhat 5?

Tags: gcc, redhat

I have developed a qt application on Ubuntu 16 but for testing I need to run it on redhat 5. But I am using c++11 standard features in my code and gcc (very old version on redhat) does not recognise this. I need to know is it possible to install gcc version (anything above than 5.0) on redhat 5?

I have already searched online but most of the links take me to redhat 7. Please note that I cannot upgrade to rhel 7.

Comment: Did you try compiling from source?

Comment: You have a Qt application written using C++11? The short answer is that what you are trying to will be impossible to maintain. You will need to rebuild Qt and a recent version of GCC so you can use those on your RHEL 5 installation to build your application. Then you will have to maintain GCC and Qt, keeping up with security vulnerabilities. IMO, you need to re-think your solution. You should either use the versions of Qt and GCC already available on the system, or switch to something newer (RHEL 8?).

Comment: Try using redhat developr tooset, here is a sample blog https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/3/html/packaging_guide/sect-enabling_the_software_collection